# Youtube API v3 : no wildcard in search?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I'm making a list of the videos of my channel, and want to use the search endpoint of the API : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Ther eis a "q" parameter to send the query. What completely bugs me is that no wildcard is referenced in the documentation, and when using * it doesn't do anything. For example, in order to find any video containing "television" in the title, the full word has to be input ! Sending "tel" won't work, nor sending "televisio".

Did I miss something ? Is there a way around this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

YouTube searching works along the same paradigm as Google searching, which is quite a bit different than the character-wildcard keyword approach. It's semantic probabilistic searching, looking for relevance based on the terms you give it, so while the * does represent a wildcard, it represents a whole word. For example, you can search for "a * saved" and it will return to you the videos which score the highest relevance score where any word could be substituted in place of your wildcard.

You can also use other punctuation based search operators ... the + sign, - sign, quotation marks, etc. Just make sure they're all URL encoded before you send the query in.